# Rails - Puma randomly failed to start a worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, puma

After upgrading from unicorn to puma, i've encounter a strange error;

Sometimes when worker are starting, they start on the bad ruby version, and so causes an error. It seems to be random...

This error causes 503 on my application because the worker is not starting properly.

this is my error :

```
app[web.3]: bundler: failed to load command: puma (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/puma)
app[web.3]: SignalException: SIGTERM
```

But I a not on ruby 2.5.0

System configuration:

Ruby version: 2.5.1

Rails version: 5.1.4

Puma version: 3.11.4

( on heroku )

Somebody has an idea ?

EDIT :

`Procfile` :

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
worker:  bundle exec rake jobs:work
shoryuken_worker:  bundle exec shoryuken -R -C config/shoryuken.yml
```

`puma.rb` :

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 4) # WEB_CONCURRENCY = 3
threads_count = Integer(ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 4) # RAILS_MAX_THREADS = 5
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

`Gemfile` :
`gem 'puma'`

`Gemfile.lock` : 
`puma (3.11.4)`

Comment: Do you start your application using `bundle exec`? i.e. `bundle exec puma`...?

Comment: yes, bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb

Comment: Than you should be fine as far as Ruby versions go. All the gems for 2.5.x versions are stored in the same folder (since they are all compatible with the same 2.5.0 Ruby API). You're using the right gem and Ruby version. Your issue is something else. make sure `puma` is in your gemfile. Please consider adding your procfile, gemfile and config.rb files to your question.

Comment: hi, thanks for the information, you'll find this in the EDIT

Comment: Your gemfile must be more than that... you're trying to use ActiveRecord and that requires more gems. Did you leave the `unicorn` gem in there? Can you recreate the failure locally? Would you get errors using the command line: `bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -w 3 -p $PORT -e production`?... sorry, I'm reaching for straws since I can't see the cause just yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting the answer here for anyone who has not figured this out yet.

```
heroku config:set "BUNDLE_DISABLE_EXEC_LOAD"="true"
```

see this thread: [github puma issue](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1438#issuecomment-337722378)